# I want to use window.matchMedia("(min-width: 720px)").matches) in following javascript code but it does not work How I use matchMedia in this code

Tags: javascript

I want to use following code for min-width of 720px and for less than 720px I want to show only slideIndex-1,slideIndex,slideIndex+1 ,Tell me how we use windowsMatchmedia in following code?

here is the script

```
<script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
     showSlides(slideIndex);
     function plusSlides1(n) {
       showSlides(slideIndex += n+4);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
         slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      for(i=0;i<slides.length;i++){
            var NewSlides2=[slideIndex-1,slideIndex,slideIndex+1,slideIndex+2,slideIndex+3];

        for (k=0; k<5; k++)
            slides[NewSlides2[k]].style.display = "inline-block";
        }
     </script>
```

Comment: Did you look here already? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Also note: you need a meta tag in your HTML. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Thanks for giving this link of that developer.mozilla it help me more.